# How to create fallback if type invalid for boost accumulator?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to write a function which allows for applying various Boost accumulator objects against various vectors of different types.

For some types, accumulator objects don't make sense.  For example, most accumulators won't work if an array of `bool` types are passed in.

Simplified the code I have looks like:

```cpp
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/count.hpp>

using namespace boost::accumulators;

template<class V, class T> static void _apply(T* ptr, size_t n) {
  accumulator_set<T, features<V> > acc;
  std::for_each(ptr, ptr + n, std::ref(acc));
};

int main() {
  bool v[] = { true, false, true };
  _apply<tag::count, bool>(v, 3);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use SFINAE to provide a run-time error message `_apply` is called with a type that doesn't make sense rather than a compiler error.

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘const std::_Bit_reference’ and ‘const bool’)
```

Comment: But why? The whole point of SFINAE is to make decisions at *compile time*. Usually, an error at compile time is a good thing, way better than an error at run time. It doesn't make much sense to go to extra trouble to convert the former to the latter.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap a number for templated C++ functions (including accumulators) and make them accessible directly in Postgres PgSQL.  

I have a function that effectively converts Postgres types to C++ types and then generates the function calls using templates.  This is all generated automatically.  

In some cases, like taking the `mean` of a boolean vector this doesn't make a lot of sense.  I want to generate an error message, not have to manually specify which operations can be applied against which types.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for template specialization. Something along these lines:

```
namespace internal {
template<typename V, typename T>
struct ApplyHelper {
  static void apply(T* ptr, size_t n) { /* general implementation here */ }
};

template<typename V>
struct ApplyHelper<V, bool> {
  static void apply(bool* ptr, size_t n) { /* report error here */ }
};
}

template<typename V, typename T>
static void _apply(T* ptr, size_t n) {
  internal::ApplyHelper<V, T>::apply(ptr, n);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Igor.  The challenge I have is that there are dozens of different functions.  For some values of `V` the function makes sense, for others it doesn't.  I'm trying to avoid having to write a specialization for each one that doesn't work - but perhaps that is my best bet.